# How to defer generic filling in typescript - for knex queries?

Tags: typescript, knex.js

Well I have a function that looks like the following, enabling loading of multiple databases based on a string identifier:

```
function getDB<TRecord extends {} = any, TResult = unknown[]>(config_name: string, maxConnections: number = 1): Knex<TRecord, TResult> {
    if (!!cfg && !!cfg.datastores && !!cfg.datastores[config_name]) {
        if (databases[config_name]) {
            return databases[config_name];
        } else {

            const config = cfg.datastores[config_name];
            const db = knex<TRecord, TResult>({
                client: 'pg',
                connection: config,
                pool: {min: 0, max: maxConnections},
            });
            databases[config_name] = db;
            return db;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('config not initialized, can\'t load db');
    }
}
```

`databases` is kind of unsafe as being of type `Knex<any, any>[]` but for now that could be ignored.

More annoying is when using this function I would use it like:

```
const someDB = getDB('some');
const users = someDB("users").select('username').where('id', 10);
```

Which works just fine, and mechanically smooth. However the typing is completely ignored. Now I notice that knex has support for rudimentary typing, and I would like to add this https://knexjs.org/#typescript-support . Naively I would do this;

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
}
const someDB = getDB('some');
const users = someDB<User>("users").select('username').where('id', 10);
//expect users to be Pick<User, username>
```

However this doesn't work, typescript still sees users as `any`. And this stems because `someDB` is being given a proper type after the call to `getDB` - which is obviously `Knex<any, unknown[]>`. A solution would be to directly infer the type when calling `getDB`:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
}
const someDB = getDB<User>('some');
const users = someDB("users").select('username').where('id', 10);
//expect users to be Pick<User, username>
```

However then on extending the code to be like:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
}
const someDB = getDB<User>('some');
const users = someDB("users").select('username').where('id', 10);
const students = someDB("student").select('name').where('id', 10);
```

This gives errors, as now `students` are also of type `User[]` which obviously doesn't have to be be the case.

So, how would I refactor this that typescript typing is forwarded until the knex function is called?

Comment: Did you manage to test the solution I proposed? If so, did you encounter any issues or is it working for your use case?

Comment: Please share `databases` and `cfg` minimum reproducable examples. Where did you get `Knex` type?

Comment: @captain-yossarian that is part of knex library. knex (version 0.98.x) natively supports typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ts Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=19&ssc=52&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gdhAHgHgCoBoqoEwD4oC8UA3gBQCGATgOYBcUA2hltgLoCU9TmOrAvgCgA9EKjAAFgEsAzrASIx4aDKjiIlaACsArtOBiA9lADGBuADNJlALaLIUSRYM3ywSWYeywG6eoBuEAAmwqIA1vKeUORQ5tpwxm4ewOShjtRQ2FDUEAiUksZ20FTU2tY5wNKYGsDalHBpckhoPHgCIVBwRtm5%20VBgVORlwOqyCEFBUElqWRDAACIAQlBD4gbBsfGJcDPzC6SmFpLUAPpwgxD0enlw1JjW5IgAwmYICe5w0vRwpQBG6oRQACM7AEUCgIig1Vq21A9nE5FkmW66l6xVK5Vk92AxikN0aiAA5LJYdADldyI5gKDwaIJNAoXVCpFohs3mZMAB3SQSMTTaTnPoDIYjKKyeBITDkOCBKD8sqQ2bQwrU%20hoABKEFMlBlSGG0tkxD4AKlIB4Guk2gANvoiHFwgYOXAGKxcKRqWCwQA6b39SiDT5QAAKQtmI2Q4pQqA1WsCZogFutuFw7qg7EI%20A1NTqqCU4fk6s1zljWHNVuASZIKYhdNlAsk1jAlogZTgyS2bQ9Cqz22%20lstoqicBAAG4q6IpWZ65IAF6ud7LI7ifR-DoQcYyxyygzy4wI%20MCQQCMn6HxgMy%20AHZXakAkc%20HDAKUAmYQEABnYpAYBJJ0gJA%20PmAElQ0DePG-hBH%20CImOewAcKOEKnueyiyAY5hMgABgwABEP5YZgWHAX0PjgYEWGsOhQA)

```
function getDB(config_name: string, maxConnections: number = 1)
   : <TRecord extends {} = any, 
      TResult = unknown[]>(
         ...params: Parameters<Knex<TRecord, TResult>>
      ) => ReturnType<Knex<TRecord, TResult>> {
   // same implementation
}
```

Move the generic arguments on the return type.
(Yes, I know this is insane, I just found out you can do this)

Define a function as the return type, taking 2 generic arguments (TRecord, TResult), then by using Knex<TRecord, TResult> (which should be a function) define a function taking Knex's parameters and returning the return type of the same function.

Type information should be properly forwarded when you call `someDb<User>('users')` later on.